# XSLT concat function

Tags: xslt

Hi all I was having a scenario to add zero in the right of value dynamically based on string length for 17 character and if it less it will add the required no of zero at the end to make it 17 character long.
`$normalizedTime2` value is dynamic one any value it can come which is less then 17 characters long.

I am trying this below approach but it is now working as expected.

Ex: if i am getting value like 2016050611525 the out put should be 20160506115250000 . the incoming value is dynamic.

```
    <xsl:variable name="normalizedTime2" select="2016050611525"/>
    <xsl:variable name="normalizedTime">
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="string-length(normalize-space($normalizedTime2)) &lt; 17">
              <xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(., '00000000000000000'),1,17)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise><xsl:value-of select="$normalizedTime2"/></xsl:otherwise>
          </xsl:choose>   
    </xsl:variable>
```

Let me know the issue .

Comment: Is your question not answered?

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your example should have:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(concat($normalizedTime2, '00000000000000000'),1,17)"/>
```

instead of:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(concat(.,'00000000000000000'),1,17)"/>
```

And I am not sure why you need the `xsl:choose` instruction - unless you expect input strings longer than 17 characters and don't want to cut them off. Otherwise you could just do:

```
<xsl:value-of select="substring(concat($inputString, '00000000000000000'), 1, 17)"/>
```

for any input.